# Making a modal (e.target)

Tags: javascript

I am following a tutorial on YouTube on how to create a modal. Here is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ophW7Ask_0). The part that confuses me occurs at 21.10 minutes.

I am trying to create a modal that should close when I click on the x button and when I click outside of the modal area but **NOT** when I click on the inside.

When at the bottom of JavaScript code, `e.target == modal`, the modal should go away when the cursor is clicked outside of the modal area but not inside.

However, in the HTML file, the `id=simpleModal` is set for the whole `div` class which is then referenced in JavaScript as a variable `modal`.

So as far as I understand, `e=modal` should apply to the whole modal section, not just the outside, and should close the window if clicked at any point, not just the outside.

My question is this - What am I missing?

```js
//Get modal element
var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');
//Get open modal button
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn');
//Get close button
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];


//Listen for click
modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);

//Listen for close clock
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

//Listen for outside click
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);


//Fucntion to open modal
function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

//Fucntion to close modal
function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}


function outsideClick(e) {
  if (e.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index=1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  margin: 20% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 10px 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<button id="modalBtn" class="button">Click Here</button>

<div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
    <p>Hello...I am a modal</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `What am I missing` the modal seems to work as expected. Does it not work for you? If your issue is trying to understand the code, debug it and add `console.log()` where needed to see the values of the objects, etc.. You can also add `debugger;` to step through the code line by line in the debugger console in a browser.

Comment: The variable modal in Javascript refers to id class simplemodal in html which includes both the modal content area and outside area. Now in the last part of Javascript, the condition is if the e.target=modal, then close the modal. But when I click on the content area - it doesn't close the modal - only when I click on the outside of modal area it closes. That's what I am trying to understand

Comment: Add `console.log()` into those functions to inspect the value or `debugger;` which will stop the code and allow you to watch the values in the browser console as you step through it. That should show you exactly why things happen the way they do.

Comment: I will try those methods now :) Thank you

Comment: I tried them but I still don't really get it :( It's just that the variable modal is defined as the whole window but then in the Javascript the outsideClick function only executed outside of Modal and not the whole window